What is Mandaeanism and is it Christian?
I can't find any CSE questions about this religion, although I think it is linked to John the Baptist.
There may be different spellings for the religion, and perhaps that's why I have been unable to find out how and when it originated and what the main beliefs are.

Probably Mandaeism? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandaeism

The reason it is not asked about, is because it isn't christian. They deny christ.

@curiousdannii Ah, that explains why I couldn't find it. Thanks for the link - greatly appreciated :-)

Mandaean Sabians (الصابئة المندائيون al-Ṣābiʾa al-Mandāʾiyyūn) or simply as Sabians (الصابئة al-Ṣābiʾa),
They are a "gnostic" religion. It is even found in the name "Manda" means "knowledge". The Gnostics in general focused on spiritual "hidden" revelations over other factors.
They are definitively not christian as they believe Jesus to be a false prophet. They regard John the Baptist as the final great prophet.

Burkitt, F. C. (1928). "The Mandaeans". The Journal of Theological Studies. 29 (115): 225–235. doi:10.1093/jts/os-XXIX.115.225. ISSN 0022-5185. JSTOR 23950943. When they were first discovered by Europeans in the 17th century, and it was found that they were neither Catholics nor Protestants but that they made much of baptism and honoured John the Baptist, they were called Christians of St John, in the belief that they were a direct survival of the Baptist's disciples. Further research, however, made it quite clear that they were not Christians or Jews at all, in any ordinary sense of the word. They regard 'Jesus Messiah' as a false prophet, and 'the Holy Spirit' as a female demon, and they denounce the Jews and all their ways.


Fundamental tenets
According to E. S. Drower, the Mandaean Gnosis is characterized by nine features, which appear in various forms in other gnostic sects. (The Numbers and order do not reflect importance here!)

A supreme formless Entity, the expression of which in time and space is a creation of spiritual, etheric, and material worlds and beings. Production of these is delegated by It to a creator or creators who originated It. The cosmos is created by Archetypal Man, who produces it in similitude to his own shape.
Dualism: a cosmic Mother and Father, Light and Darkness, Left and Right, syzygy in cosmic and microcosmic form.
As a feature of this dualism, counter-types (dmuta) that exist in a world of ideas (Mshunia Kushta).
The soul is portrayed as an exile, a captive; his home and origin being the supreme Entity to which he eventually returns.
Planets and stars influence fate and human beings, and are also the places of detention after death.
A savior spirit or savior spirits which assist the soul on his journey through life and after it to 'worlds of light'.
A cult-language of symbol and metaphor. Ideas and qualities are personified.
"Mysteries", i.e. sacraments to aid and purify the soul, to ensure its rebirth into a spiritual body, and its ascent from the world of matter. These are often adaptations of existing seasonal and traditional rites to which an esoteric interpretation is attached. In the case of the Naṣoraeans, this interpretation is based on the Creation story (see 1 and 2), especially on the Divine Man, Adam, as crowned and anointed King-priest.
Great secrecy is enjoined upon initiates; full explanation of 1, 2, and 8 being reserved for those considered able to understand and preserve the gnosis.


They make a big deal of baptism, they apparently do it every sunday!... but it is not a christian baptism.

From the position of the Orthodox Church regarding gnostics in general...

The heretics had a very good biblical verse at their disposal: “The God of this aeon has blinded the eyes of unbelievers” (2 Corinthians 4:4). It’s the orthodox themselves who are blind. But the Knowers, the Cognoscenti (for that is the true meaning of Gnostic), know better. They are special because they possess secret knowledge unknown to the orthodox. (Source Article on Eclectic Orthodoxy)


“Others, again, from the heretics fabricate for themselves another creator of all things besides the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, being greatly blinded even in what they say.” Athanasius, On the Incarnation §2


do you think they are right in their argument of a cosmic father and mother?

No. It is a fundamental error and core concept of gnostic religions. Basically they divide everything into 2, so you have 2 gods (Light/Dark). And everything "spiritual" is good and everything "material" is evil. You usually end up with the "Good god" making the spiritual realm, and the evil one made the material realm, they are opposed to each other and the battleground is the material realm. it sounds vaguely christian until you get into the weird nonsense of "secret knowledge"

Though some aspects of cosmic duality is true and that can be seen from the Bible where Adam and Eve could only make one out of two choices, they were also male and female, God and Satan, good and evil et cetera.

Some aspects, but not the formal position of it. Just because we are male and female... the others are not valid aspects. God is almighty, Satan has to beg for permission to do anything, Good existed before evil, etc... it only appears that "good and evil" have equal power right now, we know evil is absolutely doomed.

Satan needs permission because he shares in the life of God, remember God created him and that is why he fears Him. I think evil manifested itself through Satan when he chose to oppose what is good. I also think the cycle of good and evil is infinite because no one knows if in eternal past God created other worlds.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany No. Satan needs permission, because he does not actually have power. God has all the power. Clearly sin occurred within the angels before the fall of mankind but after the creation... thus evil did not exist for a period of time. Likewise, in the life to come everything will be restored and even leopards will lay with young goats. Evil will not be a thing anymore. The only time where the cycle is "infinite" is within the "finite world" we currently experience.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - As fascinating as this discussion is, may I suggest you guys take this into chat? Sufficient to know their beliefs are not Christian.

@Lesley, sure, no further comment.
